# Positioning images with known focal points within a square container using object-position

Tags: html, css, object-fit, object-position

I have a set of images which I am displaying in a grid where each grid item is a square. I have set css variables on each image describing the focal point of the image as percentages from top left, and also the aspect ratio of the image as follows:

```
<img src="/img.jpg" style="--fx: 30; --fy: 70; --aspect: 0.66" />
```

I have set the image to `object-fit: cover` and I want to use `object-position` to make the focal point be as close to the center of the square container as possible without any space around the image.

I'm sure it must be possible using `calc` and `var(--fx)` etc and I've gotten close, but not managed to find a solution that works for all cases.

You can see a codepen with everything laid out - just needs the missing piece which is the value for `object-position`

https://codepen.io/photogsy/pen/gOZovVq

Thanks!

Comment: object-position: var(--fx) var(--fy);

Comment: Or if working with ints (like in your example as opposed to in your codepen):
`object-position: calc(var(--fx) * 1%) calc(var(--fy) * 1%);`

Comment: Hi @Moob, thanks but that doesn't do it, that was the first thing I tried. Eg a portrait with focal point y of 25 needs to be 0% for the y object position.

Comment: Is using cover something that is a definite constraint? (As opposed to putting the focal point in the middle and altering width and height proportionally so the square is covered?)